# MAUI navigation with multiple parameters and timing

Tags: navigation, parameter-passing, maui

On one page, named Approvals, I have a listing of different accounting objects (Travel Orders, Expense Reports, and others).

Each can be approved or rejected.

After the approval of a TravelOrder with  ID = 7 and DocumentType = TravelOrder, for instance, I would like to switch to a page named "Approved" where I would like to show a list of already approved objects and also select the TravelOrder I have just processed.

So therefore after changing the status of the object above to "Approved", I execute this line:

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//Approved?refreshData={true}&documentMode={thisExpenseReport.DocumentMode}&id={thisExpenseReport.ID}", true);`

In Approved_VM I have these query attributes:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(RefreshData), "refreshData")]
[QueryProperty(nameof(DocumentMode), "documentMode")]
[QueryProperty(nameof(ID), "id")]
```

I have

```
public string DocumentMode
        {
            set => _documentMode = value;
        }       
    public string ID
        {
            set => _id = value;
        }   
    public string RefreshData
        {            
            set
            {
                PopulateList();
                SelectApprovedObject();
            }
        }
```

On first showing the page Approved I only execute PopulateList() because in the constructor of Approved.xaml.cs I have the call

```
await viewModel.PopulateList();
```

If I am coming from Approvals, however, I would like to requery the data from the server and also to select the object with ID=7 and DocumentType = TravelOrder, as you can see in my setter for RefreshData.

However, the setter of RefreshData is executed first, and therefore SelectApprovedObject() is executed before setting the values of _documentMode and _id.

This does NOT work.

How could I implement this?

Again, I need to navigate from Approvals to Approved, requery the data pertaining to the status "Approved", and select a specific object by ID.

Comment: I would package all of those parameters into a single object that is passed, so you can handle them all at once

Comment: @Jason if you look at his code, he is using the setter to run a code. He is looking for a way to execute some code, not pass value. "RefreshData=true" will be the same as "RefreshData="false", or "RefreshData=abcd1234".

Comment: Yes, but he also wants to run Refresh after all parameters have been set.  AFAIK there is no way to guarantee they will be evaluated in a certain order, so packaging the in a single object allows some control over that

Comment: Thank you, all ! I had an idea, I plan to test it tonight: I would use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0 after setting my parameters' values. Oh, and, BTW, this could really help me - I have 5 pages which should refresh, not just one, so I'm thinking that if I would broadcast a message saying "Friends, refresh yourselves !" this could do the trick.  I will have news soon !

Answer (score 0):

First, implement IQueryAttributable interface like that:

```
public partial class MyViewModel: ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
```

Then, implement the method:

```
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
```

Last, access your data with:

```
query[nameof(RefreshData)];
query[nameof(DocumentMode)];
query[nameof(ID)];
```

And assign them in any order you like.